# Scaling dependent variables

Tags: feature-scaling

In a regression model is there a need to scale/normalize a dependent/response variable when doing the same for independent variables? If not then why?
An example will be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to data science SE. You will probably get a better answer on stats stackexchange. This is more a statistics question than pure data science.